# IE9 cannot display the webpage in iframe

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm using iframe to load an application in my HTML code. But it is redirecting to 'Internet Explorer cannot display the web page' page - When I click on the 'Go back to the previous page' link, it is loading the application.

This happens only the application loaded initially after opening the IE9 browser. Its working fine in other browsers even IE8.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?